Is there any way to limit a class to be used in certain classes?
Let's say that I have a class called Client and it has a private property called Address (a class). I don't want Address to be used in other classes than Client. Is there anything like that in Java?
I don't want to limit only to Client but I want to limit to only few classes that I want to use, like a group of classes that deal with certain work so that other developers do not use my classes in unrelated places.

Make it a private, static nested class? Would that satisfy your requirements?

Isn't that what private is? private static class Address{} would create a class that only Client has access to.

What exactly do you mean by "don't want [...] to be used in other classes"? Making it a private static inner class may be one way. Another way would be using modules (oracle.com) (if the general structure of the application is a fit for the module system).

You can make Address package-private if you want to use it in some (but more than one) class.

But in general, limiting access to data can help build data consistency guarantees, while limiting access to data-structures only gives the small benefit of avoiding namespace pollution.

how does it 'lack detail or clarity'? The comments here could be packaged into an answer.

@julaine "The comments here could be packaged into an answer." - No they could not. The post lacks information; the comments are speculative. For a clear answer, we would need more context and details. This is why I asked for clarification and voted to close as needing details (which is still missing).

@Turing85 To me the question reads as "What features does Java offer to reduce visibility of a class?" and the comments read as "Here are three techniques: private static inner classes, java9-modules and package-private classes". Looks like a fine QA to me. An "is there anything like that?"-question can hardly be expected to have one definitive answer unless you already have a specific answer in mind when writing the question.

You might want to check this out, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Classes that are package-private can only be accessed from classes in the same package, but not from any other classes:
package com.example.demo;

public class Client {} // can be accessed outside of package
class Address {}  // can only be accessed from Client or Contract
class Contract {} // can only be accessed from Client or Address

Alternatively, if you need a class to be only accessible from a single other class, consider making it a private, static nested class:
public class Client {
  private static class Address {} // can only be accessed by Client (and other nested classes of Client)
}

